# Data Transfer artefacts in Blender 2.79

Tags: shaders, faces, snapping

part of my loop, which I am trying to solder with a mesh is displayed incorrectly.[image]

and, if you move the mesh with the DataTransfer along the surface of another mesh, then the loop becomes incorrect in other places.[image]

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer! The fact is that there is not enough geometry in the main mesh. if you add horizontal loops, then the mapping becomes correct.

[image]

[image]